# Use PL/SQL to return a time period that systimestamp currently belongs to

Tags: oracle, systimestamp

i.e.

- I planned to divide 24 hours into 24 sections (1 hour for each section):
  00:30:00 AM to 01:29:59 AM as 1st section and so on
- Current `systimestamp = "02-NOV-15 06.13.49.000000000 PM"`
  I want to get the SQLs that can return a time period from 5:30:00 PM to 6:29:59 PM, which is the time period the systimestamp currently belongs to.

I have no idea how to write this SQL as beginner, thanks for any of your inputs.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to see the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. SO is not a code delivery service, so please start on your side and ask back once you get stuck in a specific problem!

Comment: i will learn the policy. thanks for the information

Answer (score 5):

You can subtract half an hour, truncate the value, and then add back half an hour.  Something like this:

```
select trunc(systimestamp - 0.5/24, 'hh') + 0.5/24
```

You can also use `interval '30' minute`:

```
select trunc(systimestamp - interval '30' minute, 'hh') + interval '30' minute
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it does help, i used the trunc functions to get a start point and an end point, which gives me the time period on demand. it's really helpful. I have tried many date and time functions,but not in the right way as you suggested.